# How do I use the Array.filter() function to remove a single element from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

I'm not sure if I'm using the filter function correctly to remove an element from an array. I would like to set it up so when I click on the element, it will remove the element. But, currently it is deleting all of the elements instead of just the one. The elements come from clicking on items displayed on the screen (these items are from an API)

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    query: "",
    contacts: [],
    names: []
  };

  addName = (e, name) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      names: [...prevState.names, name]
    }));
  };
```

This is where it messes up. I'm not sure why it deletes all the names when I click on one name

```
  removeName = (e, name) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      names: prevState.names.filter(n => n.name !== name)
    }));
  };

  onChange = e => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    this.setState({
      query: value
    });

    this.query(value);
  };

  query = query => {
    const url = ("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");

    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ contacts: data.response });
      });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.query("");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Type names to add"
            onChange={this.onChange}
          />
          {this.state.contacts.map(contact => (
            <div key={contact.name}>
              <p>
                {contact.name}{" "}
                <button
                  onClick={e => this.addName(e, contact.name)}> Add 
                 </button>   
              </p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </form>

        {this.state.names.map(name => (
          <p key={name.name}>
            {name}{" "}
            <button
              onClick={e => this.removeName(e, name.name)}>
            </button>
          </p>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried logging the `name` before `setState`?

Comment: Hmm when I use console.log(name) it comes up as undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the person who posted the original answer but deleted it actually had the right idea. When you `addNames`, you're adding strings. The names array consists of strings, not objects. Thus, when you go back into your `removeNames` function, each element `n` is a string, and `n.name` is `undefined` (i.e., `n` is the name, `n.name` is nothing). Therefore, `n.name !== name` will always be true (i.e., every name in the array *is* defined). You want to instead just compare `n` to `name` ( `n !== name` ) .

```
    removeName = (e, name) => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          names: prevState.names.filter(elmName => elmName !== name)
        }));
    }
```

And in onclick:

```
    <button
       onClick={e => this.removeName(e, name)}>
    </button>
```

And just one final thing to consider: this will only work if the names are unique. If there are the same names in the array, more than 1 element is at risk of being removed. Therefore, it may be desired to devise a scheme for ensuring uniqueness. I.e., name + [it's position in the array] is a quick-and-dirty way, although there are better ways.

Comment: I think what you are saying is to do prevState.bag.filter(d => d !== deviceTitle) instead of prevState.bag.filter(d => d.title !== deviceTitle) right? If so, I tried this and it doesn't seem to change anything, it still deletes all the elements

Comment: Even easier than that (I think). I just edited it with the block of code to update. Let me know how far it gets you.

Comment: Thank you for formatting in the block! I tried it this way as well and when I do this, it doesn't allow the removal of any elements.... when I have it written the original way, it will remove 1 element if that's all that's in there, but if I have multiple names it just removes them all

Comment: Doing that still removes everything :/ I tried elemName.name === name as well and that has no effect when I try to remove

Comment: Try with *different* names: `var names = ['Jack', 'Jill', 'Joseph']`. If I do something like: `names .filter( elmName => elmName !== "Joseph" )`, that gives me the array `["Jack", "Jill"]`, with "Joseph" removed. If however, I had the array all the same names, say "Jack" and I said to remove "Joseph", nothing would be removed.

Comment: Omg I figured out my mistake...when I called removeName in the onClick, I was passing in name.name when it should have just been name. Now your original suggestion works! Thanks so much!!

Comment: Hooray. Glad I could help :)